# Increase R studio's connection timeout limit

Tags: r, curl

Is it possible to increase R-studio's connection time out limit? I am getting the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

The below line of code caused the initial error. I am trying to use google speech to text Api through the package 'googleLanguageR'. However, I managed to install 'googleLanguageR' using `install.packages("googleLanguageR")`and now the code is failing when I try to use the `gl_auth` function in package googleLanguageR. So it's to do with the connection, hence I want to know if the time out limit can be increased.

```
devtools::install_github("MarkEdmondson1234/googleLanguageR")
```

I tried using the below commands to try to increase the limit but still getting the same error.

```
options(timeout = 4000000) 
timeout(4000000)
```

This also means that the limit specified in the above commands have not been registered because the error message still appears after 10000 milliseconds. I also tried increasing the limit to 40000, incase the above value was too big but still the same error. The only difference is that the error now times out after 10015 milliseconds. Please help!

Comment: Please, post also the line that caused the error. You are also using other packages (guess you are using `curl` here). You should post them also. What have this to do specifically with rstudio?

Comment: Thanks. I have added more clarity to my question.

Comment: Unless your internet is super super slow it shouldn't timeout, I guess its more likely the authentication isn't configured correctly. Are you following the auth guide on the website? http://code.markedmondson.me/googleLanguageR/index.html

Comment: The timeout value you are trying to set could be too large. The [manual states](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/connections.html) that your OS might interpret very large values as zero. Though POSIX standards specify that at least 31 days (i.e. 2.678.400 seconds) should be supported, there is still some uncertainty. Try using something that is even smaller than 40.000. If we keep in mind that the value we set with `options` is in *seconds* while the error message gives us *milliseconds* it is clear that we can use much smaller values to overcome 10.015 ms of timeout.

Answer (score 9):

I also faced this problem recently when trying to install the stringi packaged. I think it occurs due to a slow internet connection. Run the code below:

```r
options(timeout = max(1000, getOption("timeout")))
```

This should increase the timeout duration sufficiently.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Small question: since the OP tried setting the timeout with `options(timeout = 4000000) `  what does your solution add to fix the problem?

Comment: does this really work?

Comment: @stats_noob it seems to have worked for my program. I used a value of 200. I think the default value (at the time of writing) is 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Update the AWS default region using Sys.env() could be the solution