# RStudio hanging while installing "BH" package when deploy

Tags: r, deployment, rstudio

Hi I have an app wanted to publish on RStudio Connect.

However it hangs forever at step `Installing BH (1.84.0-0)`. Then it failed.

Tried to install this package locally but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Sharing sessionInfo and deploy log below:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.3.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0
```

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  'curl' call had nonzero exit status
curl: HTTP 000 https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/BH/BH_1.84.0-0.tar.gz
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
curl: HTTP 000 https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/BH/BH_1.84.0-0.tar.gz
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
curl: HTTP 000 https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/BH/BH_1.84.0-0.tar.gz
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
curl: HTTP 000 https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/BH/BH_1.84.0-0.tar.gz
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
curl: HTTP 000 https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/BH/BH_1.84.0-0.tar.gz
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
FAILED
Error in getSourceForPkgRecord(pkgRecord, srcDir(project), availablePackagesSource(repos = repos), : Failed to retrieve package sources for BH 1.84.0-0 from CRAN (internet connectivity issue?)
Unable to fully restore the R packages associated with this deployment.
Please review the preceding messages to determine which package
encountered installation difficulty and the cause of the failure.
Warning message:
In packrat::restore(overwrite.dirty = TRUE, prompt = FALSE, restart = FALSE) :
  The most recent snapshot was generated using R version 4.3.2
Error code: r-cannot-access-repo
RStudio Connect cannot download a package because the R package repository (for example, CRAN or RStudio Package Manager) cannot be accessed.
Possible causes:
* There is a network problem preventing the Connect server from connecting to the package repository.
* The package repository may be down.
* The package repository must be accessed through a proxy server, but no proxy server is configured in the Connect configuration file.
* The client computer that published the content is using a different package repository from the Connect server, and that package repository is not accessible from the Connect server.
* The package repository has moved to a different URL since the content was published.

Possible solutions:
* Verify that the package repository is reachable from the Connect server.
* If necessary, change the Packages.HTTPProxy and Packages.HTTPSProxy configuration settings to point to your outbound proxy server.
* Configure the client with a package repository that is accessible via http(s) from the Connect server, such as CRAN or RStudio Package Manager. Reinstall the affected packages from the new repository and publish the content again.

References:
* https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/admin/r/package-management/#proxy-configuration
* https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/admin/appendix/configuration/#Packages.HTTPProxy
* https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004067074-Managing-Packages-with-RStudio

Additional data:
Package: 'BH'
PackageVersion: '1.84.0-0'
Packages.HTTPProxy: 'ltx1-itpxy.XXXX.XXX:XXXX'
Packages.HTTPSProxy: 'ltx1-itpxy.XXXX.XXX:XXXX'
Found in the following log entry:
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
Build error: RStudio Connect cannot download a package because the R package repository (for example, CRAN or RStudio Package Manager) cannot be accessed. (r-cannot-access-repo)
── Deployment complete ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✖ Deployment failed with error: RStudio Connect cannot download a package because the R package repository (for example, CRAN or RStudio Package Manager) cannot be accessed. (r-cannot-access-repo)
```

Comment: Try running `options(timeout = 6000)` before you install BH and see if you get the same error

Comment: Hi @jared_mamrot! I ran that command in my console before clicking "publish". Now in deploy log it keep displaying ```GET /__api__/tasks/qZRVjO8G1IdqYU2B?first_status=21 447ms
GET /__api__/tasks/qZRVjO8G1IdqYU2B?first_status=21 421ms
GET /__api__/tasks/qZRVjO8G1IdqYU2B?first_status=21 424ms
GET /__api__/tasks/qZRVjO8G1IdqYU2B?first_status=21 420ms```

Comment: Try a larger number? E.g. 4000000 (per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262384/increase-r-studios-connection-timeout-limit). Also, if you haven't already, post your question to the posit community at https://community.rstudio.com/